# Use grep to extract specific words from a string under conditions and print it to variable file names

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a sample file like this:

**r** **2.1238** /NodeList/**1**/DeviceList/1/ ( type=0x806, source=00:00, destination=ff:ff) ns3::**IPv4Header** (source ipv4: 10.1.2.1 dest ipv4: 10.1.2.4)

**+** **2.0076** /NodeList/**0**/DeviceList/1/ ( type=0x806, source=00:00, destination=ff:ff) ns3::**ArpHeader** (source ipv4: 10.1.2.1 dest ipv4: 10.1.2.4)

**-** **2.0077** /NodeList/**1**/DeviceList/1/ ( type=0x806, source=00:00, destination=ff:ff) ns3::**IPv4Header** (source ipv4: 10.1.2.1 dest ipv4: 10.1.2.4)

**d** **4.0042** /NodeList/**2**/DeviceList/1/ ( type=0x806, source=00:00, destination=ff:ff) ns3::**IPv4Header** (source ipv4: 10.1.2.1 dest ipv4: 10.1.2.4)

and so on.

The bold parts are the important fields. The first field can be '-', '+', 'r' or 'd'. The second field has a time stamp, in bold. Third field is to be the Node number, again in bold. The node number refers to the file to which the previous two fields is to be printed.

The restriction is that I want data from only those lines containing **IPv4Header**, eg. 1st, 3rd and 4th line in above sample.

So, I want my output to be like:

Node0.txt:
+ 2.0076

Node1.txt:
r 2.1238
- 2.0077

As you can see Node0 in line 2 is rejected as it does not contain **IPv4Header**. As we can see the number of output files being generated is equal to the number of nodes having **IPv4Header**.

Assume the number of lines and nodes to be multiple and variable for different files. Can someone please provide me with the necessary grep code?

Comment: why don't you have `Node2 d 4.0042`?

Comment: Why don't you try to solve this yourself, then ask for help with the parts of your solution with which you're having problems? StackOverflow isn't intended for handouts of custom solutions. Check out the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation for tips on what goes in to a good question.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F/ '/IPv4Header/{print $1 > "Node" $3 ".txt" }' file
```

should create two files with contents

```
Node1.txt: r 2.1238 
           - 2.0077 
Node2.txt: d 4.0042
```

note that `Node0` won't be created as per your definition.

Comment: That's certainly nice, what about the `':'` after `txt`? I really have to work more with `awk`...

Comment: that was a testing artifact, removed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually looking for is `sed`. For example, using `sed` you could do the following:

```
$ sed -n '/IPv4Header/s/^\([+-rd]\)[ ]*\([0-9.]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]\).*$/Node\3.txt \1 \2/p' file
Node1.txt r 2.1238
Node1.txt - 2.0077
Node2.txt d 4.0042
```

Where

- `sed -n`  suppresses normal outoput,
- `/IPv4Header/`  locate only lines containing `IPv4Header`

What following is the standard `sed` substitute `s/match/replace/` where `match` uses capture groups `\(stuff\)` to save `stuff` for use in `replace` using *backreferences* where `\1`, `\2`... is replaced with `stuff1`, `stuff2`, etc..

- `^\([+-rd]\)` save the first character if it is one of `+-rd` in capture group 1,
- `[ ]*` skip any number of spaces,
- `\([0-9.]*\)` save sequence of `0-9` and `.` in capture group 2,
- `[^0-9]*` skip anything not a `0-9`,
- `\([0-9]\)` capture the next number in capture group 3,
- `.*$` skip remaining chars
- `/Node\3 \1 \2/` replace with the backreferences in the order shown
- `p` print it.

Give it a try and let me know if it is doing what you need.

Comment: I want the result to be outputed to the respective text files of the nodes (named node0.txt, node1.txt, etc..). Is that possible?

Comment: With bash `while read -r name rest; do echo "$rest" >> "$name.txt"; done < <(sed ..... file)` That would write `r 2.1238` and `- 2.0077` (on separate lines) to `Node1.txt`, etc.. **note the space** in `done < <(sed..`

Comment: **note:** you can simply use `"$name"` in the comment above after I edited the answer to append `'.txt'` following `NodeX`